# Python argparse seems not to support too long arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, argparse

i create an script with the following args:

```
def arguments():
    ''' gets arguments '''

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="This scripts start the setup for the project, this setup is defined by the Core \
                     Module of each Setup, so first it download the scripts from that module and \
                     proceed to run them from a temporal directory installing the desired \
                     components and applying the configuration."
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--project_name",
        help="The name for the project",
        type=str,
        required=True)

    parser.add_argument(
        "--project_dir",
        help="The dir where to create the project",
        type=str,
        required=True)

    parser.add_argument(
        "--core_npm_package",
        type=str,
        help="The NPM core package",
        required=True)

    parser.add_argument(
        "--npm_packages",
        nargs='+',
        type=str,
        help="The NPM package for install if no source code is required",
        required=True)

    ''' the modules data array in JSON format, it follows the structure defined in 
        src/app/modules/setup.module/vos/module.vo.ts '''

    parser.add_argument(
        "--modules_data",
        type=str,
        help="The data of each module in JSON format",
        required=True)

    return parser.parse_args()
```

Then when i try to run the script using python3 with the following arguments:

```
python3 run_setup.py --project_name TEST_PROJECT --project_dir /home/diego/Desktop/ --npm_packages @creard_nativescript_ng/auth.module --core_npm_package @creard_nativescript_ng/core.module --modules_data 'some long json or any data'
```

I got the output:

```
usage: run_setup.py [-h] [--project_name PROJECT_NAME]
                    [--project_dir PROJECT_DIR]
run_setup.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --npm_packages @creard_nativescript_ng/auth.module --core_npm_package @creard_nativescript_ng/core.module --modules_data [{"moduleName":"auth.module","package":"@creard_nativescript_ng/auth.module","options":{"loginConfig":{"title":"title modified"}}}]
```

But if i remove any argument (also --modules_data that i think is the culprit) always points that i miss some argument, no matter which argument, but all together don't work.

Comment: I copy-n-pasted your code and input, and it ran fine.

Comment: Look at the `usage` in the error message.  That isn't the usage for the parser that you show.  It's for some other parser, one that only recognizes two arguments.  All the arguments in this parser are `required`.  Double check by asking for the help, `-h`.

Comment: @hpaulj that's the weird thing, when i run the same script whitout that parameters the usage show me more parameters requiere (the others threesome) but using them the usage show me that i can only use two

Comment: Sounds like there's another parser, possibly in an imported module.

Comment: You are right i include anorher script that also use argsparse, how i can conditionally ignore it in the other script?

Comment: A well structured module puts the `parser` call in an `if __name__....` block so it only runs when used as a script, not via `import`.

Comment: Yeah, putting `if __name__ == '__main__'` solved the problem, because i included the scripts using `imp.load_source`, later i will put the solution as answer