# myscript.py: error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I seem to be having an issue with a program I am working on in python. I have tried using sys.argv, getopt and now argparse and I am still having the same issues. Whenever I try to call myscript.py from the command line with any working arguments, the program appears to start up then it just exits the code and prints the following in the command line:

```
Loading configurations...                        <---- indicates program is starting
usage: myprogram.py [-h] [-c string] [-v]
miner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -i 0 -d 0
```

### myprogram.py snippet

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i','--interval', action="store", type=int, dest='interval',help='Amount of time between each switch in seconds.')
parser.add_argument('-d','--donate', action="store", type=int,dest='donate',help='Amount of time to donate your mining rig in percentage per hour.')

results = parser.parse_args()

class globalbavars:
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        interval = 8
        donate = 1

    interval = results.interval
    donate = results.donate
```

I usually almost always figure out issues with my program on my own through fierce debugging but this one legitimately has me scratching my head. I can't figure out what is causing this issue. I don't even think that it's an issue with my code considering I've tried parsing with sys.argv, get opt and argparse and got the same results. Can someone help me out?

Comment: How are you running this? I just ran your script in PyCharm and it seems to work fine for me with no errors. Passing -i 1 and -d 5 I get both them as donate = int 5 and interval = int 1. All I added was the imports.

Comment: I am editing the code in vs code and running it from the command line.@Carson

Comment: `$ python myprogram.py -i 5 -d 6
    Interval  5
    Donate  6`

Get the same thing doing the command line way on Windows (added those print statements). Maybe it's a 2.7 vs 3.x issue or something with your Python install? What I just ran was with 2.7

Comment: Look at the `usage`.  It doesn't fit your parser definition.  You probably have another `parser` in your code, possibly imported.  Same issue in this recent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715099/python-argparse-seems-not-to-support-too-long-arguments